# CSS transition not working on Safari even with prefixes

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions, bootstrap-5

I'm having an issue where circular pictures are changing to squares on hover. I'm using Bootstrap 5. This is only happening in Safari. I've narrowed down the issue to the CSS transition. I've added all the necessary prefixes to make this work on Safari so I'm not sure what else to try here.

Run the snippet below in Safari and you will be able to see the error.

```css
/*  container for people photos */
#people-container {
    padding-top:10px;
  }



/*  Bio info container (name, title) */
.bio-holder {
  padding-top:10px;
}

/*  Bio name */
.people_name {
  padding-top:2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#0c2d1c !important
}

/*  Bio title */
.mb-0 {
  color:#004869 !important;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:500 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase
}



/*  Bio image container */
.img-holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}



/*  Scaling bio image on hover */
.img-fluid.d-block.mx-auto:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.img-fluid.d-block.mb-3.mx-auto:focus {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="py-5 text-center text-info background-info" style="">
  <div class="container" id="people-container">
    <div id="parent" class="row">

      <!-- Lead Scientists -->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 p-4 holly-gibbs lead-scientist">
        <div class="img-holder">
          <a style='color:none' href="holly-gibbs.html"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="https://uwmadison.box.com/shared/static/nkynh2ad7qfspe2dhmg305aqdun4hase.png" alt="Card image cap" width="200">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bio-holder">
          <a style='color:none' href="holly-gibbs.html">
            <h4 class="people_name"> <b>Holly Gibbs</b> </h4>
            <p class="mb-0">PROFESSOR AND DIRECTOR OF GLUE LAB</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 p-4 lead-scientist">
        <div class="img-holder">
          <a style='color:none' href="tyler-lark.html"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto " src="https://uwmadison.box.com/shared/static/nkynh2ad7qfspe2dhmg305aqdun4hase.png" alt="Card image cap" width="200">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bio-holder">
          <a style='color:none' href="tyler-lark.html">
            <h4 class="people_name"> <b>Tyler Lark</b> </h4>
            <p class="mb-0">LEAD SCIENTIST</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you may use https://picsum.photos/  in your snippet...

Comment: Just a note that you generally don't need to worry anymore about prefixes for most common things like [transition](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition) or [transform](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d), especially if it's just a visual enhancement that's not going to break anything meaningful and only for obsure or outdated browsers. Of course there are exceptions to this, but often nowadays it's just clutter.

Comment: I now realize this question is also a repost of yet a previous question of yours. Please edit that one too.